# Which is a better approach for this particular case of varargs in Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I have the following definition on Scala

```
     def seq(stms: Stm*): Stm = if (stms.isEmpty) EXP(CONST(0)) else stms reduce SEQ
```

I use it to write stms like:

```
  ESEQ(
    seq(MOVE(TEMP(r), CONST(1)),
      genstm(t, f),
      LABEL(f),
      MOVE(TEMP(r), CONST(0)),
      LABEL(t)),
    TEMP(r))
```

But in some case i need that "the last element of the sequence to be a list" so, i write:

```
ESEQ (seq(
  EXP(extenalCall("_newRecord", expressions.length)) ::
  MOVE(rt, Frame.RV) ::
  values:_*
  ), rt)
```

I whould like to be more homogeneous in how "seq" is called. I did method overloading:

```
  def seq(stms: List[Stm]): Stm = if (stms.isEmpty) EXP(CONST(0)) else stms reduce SEQ

  def seq(s1:Stm, l:List[Stm]) = seq(s1 :: l)
  def seq(s1:Stm, s2:Stm, l:List[Stm]) = seq(s1 :: s2 :: l)
  def seq(s1:Stm, s2:Stm, s3:Stm, l:List[Stm]) = seq(s1 :: s2 :: s3 :: l)
  def seq(s1:Stm, s2:Stm, s3:Stm, s4:Stm, l:List[Stm]) = seq(s1 :: s2 :: s3 :: s4 ::  l)
  def seq(s1:Stm, s2:Stm, s3:Stm, s4:Stm, s5:Stm, l:List[Stm]) = seq(s1 :: s2 :: s3 :: s4 :: s5 :: l)

  def seq(s:Stm*) = seq(s.toList)
```

In order to write the last snippet like this:

```
ESEQ (seq(
  EXP(extenalCall("_newRecord", expressions.length)),
  MOVE(rt, Frame.RV),
  values
  ), rt)
```

There's a different approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best idea that I can come up with is to define an implicit conversion from `Stm` to `List[Stm]`, and then accept any number of `List[Stm]`:

```
implicit def stm2list(stm: Stm): List[Stm] = List(stm)

def seq(stms: List[Stm]*): Stm = {
  val flat = stms.flatten
  if (flat.isEmpty) EXP(CONST(0)) else stms reduce SEQ
}
```

But then it will also be valid for any of the first elements to be a `List[Stm]`, not just the last one.

It also introduces a dangerous implicit conversion. You can protect it with a tiny class that will wrap the `List[Stm]` in a different type, then provide 2 implicit conversions:

```
class ListOfStmOrStm(val stms: List[Stm])
object ListOfStmOrStm {
  implicit def fromStm(stm: Stm): ListOfStmOrStm = new ListOfStmOrStm(List(stm))
  implicit def fromList(stms: List[Stm]): ListOfStmOrStm = new ListOfStmOrStm(stms)
}

def seq(stms: ListOfStmOrStm*): Stm = {
  val flat = stms.flatMap(_.stms)
  if (flat.isEmpty) EXP(CONST(0)) else stms reduce SEQ
}
```

Note: it is useless to make `ListOfStmOrStm` a value class, since it will have to be boxed to be stored in the `Seq` that comes with the `*` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Seq()` and `++` to keep on using commas:

```
ESEQ(seq(Seq(
    x,
    y,
    z) ++ values: _*),
  ...)
```

Or if you can write `seq()` in such a way that

```
seq(xs: _*) ++ seq(ys: _*) == seq((xs ++ ys): _*)
```

then you could avoid writing `Seq()`:

```
ESEQ(seq(
  x,
  y,
  z) ++ seq(values: _*),
  ...)
```